# Function with product of sine kernel

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ be such that $\hat{f}$ is supported on $[-\pi,\pi]$. Also, $f$ is continuous and goes to $0$ at $\pm \infty$. Let $$K_\lambda(y)=\dfrac{2\sin(\pi(\lambda-1)y)\sin(\pi(\lambda+1)y)}{\pi^2 y^2(\lambda-1)}$$ How can we show that $$f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\lambda}f\left(\frac{n}{\lambda}\right)K_\lambda\left(x-\frac{n}{\lambda}\right)$$ for every $x$?

I'm not sure how to start with this.

Comment: Is there a typo in this question? It seems you are claiming that $f(x)$ can be written in terms of $f(x/\lambda)$ alone. Surely that is not true?

Comment: Where does this formula come from? Are you sure there is not still a typo? I mean if you take the limit $\lambda\to 1^+$ we don't get exactly the formula you gave in your post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586415/writing-function-as-infinite-fourier-sum-with-sine-kernel

Comment: This is very similar to Shannon's reconstruction theorem, do you know it?

Comment: Does $f$ depend on $\lambda$ as well? Did you forget to put in front of $f$ something like $\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition that $\hat f$ is supported on an interval $(-a, a)$ means that $f$ belongs to the Paley-Wiener space $PW_a$. As far as I understand, your function $K_\lambda$ is the reproducing kernel of this space, which means that for every $f$ from the space we have $(f, K_\lambda)=f(\lambda)$. The reproducing kernels at real points that form an arithmetic progression with step $a$, form an orthogonal basis on the Paley-Wiener space, and your formula is a decomposition of $f$ with respect to this basis.