# Generalization of Shannon's Reconstruction Theorem

Tags: fourier-analysis, information-theory

Suppose $f$ is of moderate decrease and that its Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ is supported in $I=[-1/2, 1/2]$, $\lambda > 1$. Show that:
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\lambda}f(\frac{n}{\lambda})K_{\lambda}(x-\frac{n}{\lambda})
$$
where
$$
K_{\lambda}(y)=\frac{\cos{\pi y} -\cos{\pi\lambda y}}{\pi^2(\lambda-1)y^2}.
$$

**My approach:** Let $g(x)=\hat{f}(\lambda x)$, then by the Poisson summation formula we have
$$
g(x)=\frac{1}{\lambda}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}f\left( \frac{n}{\lambda} \right)e^{ -2\pi inx }
$$
by Fourier inversion we have
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(\xi)e^{ 2\pi i\xi x } \, d\xi=\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}g\left( \frac{\xi}{\lambda} \right)e^{ 2\pi i\xi x } \, d\xi   \\
&=\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\lambda}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}f\left( \frac{n}{\lambda} \right)e^{ -2\pi in \frac{\xi}{\lambda} }e^{ 2\pi i\xi x } d\xi \\
&=\frac{1}{\lambda}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}f\left( \frac{n}{\lambda} \right) \frac{\sin\left( \pi\left( x-\frac{n}{\lambda} \right) \right)}{\pi\left( x-\frac{n}{\lambda} \right)}
\end{align}
$$
I'm not sure what's wrong with my calculations. The hint on page 167 in Stein's book *Fourier Analysis* is really confusing me, and I don't know how to "replace" the characteristic function so I didn't proceed with that approach.

I've also seen a similar problem on [Function with product of sine kernel](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/588645/1033621), but I don't understand the answer given because of my limited knowledge.

Any help would be appreciated!